# Pre save and post read actions

Tags: android, realm

I am using realm.io in Android. 
I just started using realm so my question is bit basic. I want to know

- How to do pre-save action on realm object ? Like I want to run some calculation on the in coming data before saving them
- How to do post-read operation before handing over the object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how do you want to achieve it.

You can wrapper a function do to it like

```
public static void setValue(Something something, int value) {
    value = value + 42;
    something.setValue(value);
}

realm.beginTransaction();
setValue(something, 42);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Or you can just use the setter to wrap the logic like:

```
public class Something extends RealmObject {
    private int value;
    public void setValue(int value) {
        value = value + 42;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Getters are similar.